# How to match a word and take action on basis of that

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to use the following command to go in subfolders and find the term accuracy or converged and if not found then copy the output file to input file and submit the job. My code

```
for i in V*/*/ ;
 do cd $i;
 if ["$(accuracy)" != "$(grep 'accuracy' OUTCAR)"]; then
 mv CONTCAR POSCAR ;
 qsub job_script ; 
 fi 
done
```

But it's not working. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `if` is rather strange: `!==` isn't valid; use `!=`; put a space after `[` and before `]`, these are a shell command & argument, respectively.

Comment: use: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It's also likely that `accuracy` is not a shell utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attempt:

```
for i in V*/*/; do
 (cd "$i"
 if ! grep -q 'accuracy' OUTCAR ; then
   mv CONTCAR POSCAR
   qsub job*    # ???
 fi)
done
```

Comment: Don't drop the `( )`. The subshell is important to keep from changing the directory of the outer parts of the script.